# Using php and Mysql to Order by highest number and confirmation

Tags: php, mysql, post, rows

Well I have this mysql table with numbers in one column and a confirmation boolean of 0 or 1 and I have about 1,000 rows so it's not something I can do manually but anyways...
I want to sort the row by highest value and grab the names of the first 5 people and put those 5 people in another table on a column and then set them to confirmed and continue until there's no one left in the table that isn't confirmed...
ex:

```
Name:Rank:Confirm
Bob:5000:0
James:34:0
Josh:59:1
Alex:48:0
Romney:500:0
Rolf:24:0
Hat:51:0
```

so when you run the code it will do the following:

```
Squad:Name1:Name2:Name3:Name4:Name5
1:Bob:Romney:Hat:Alex:James
```

(as you can see Josh was excluded and Rolf was too low)

And since Rolf is alone and there are no one else left, he wont be put into a team and will be left unconfirmed...

I'm not really pro at mysql so I was stumped on this and at most was capable of organizing the whole thing by rank and that's it ._.

edit:
The terrible attempt I had at this:

```
<?php 
$parse = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(rank) AS rank FROM users AND confirm='0'");
mysql_query("Insert into squad (nameone)values($parse)");
mysql_query("Update squad set confirm = '1' where name = $parse");
?>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to organize by rank and then use explode + foreach to split the variable apart and then insert for every 5(got stumped after there was remainders left) but then I figured that it was just a mess the way I was trying to sort the values into teams and felt like it could've been done with just mysql or mostly mysql. ><

Comment: Post your attempt anyway, so we have a starting point

Comment: there, it's the best I got and it honestly didn't turn out anywhere close to what I wanted and I was stumped after I realized I couldn't tell it to add on to the first squad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming confirm will have only either 1 or 0.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255));
CREATE PROCEDURE rank()
BEGIN
   DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 1;
   WHILE count > 0 DO
      UPDATE table1 SET Confirm=2 WHERE Confirm=0 ORDER BY Rank DESC LIMIT 5; 
      INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name) FROM table1 WHERE Confirm=2);
      UPDATE table1 SET Confirm=1 WHERE Confirm=2;
      SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE Confirm=0;
   END WHILE;
END;
```

Call the procedure rank() when ever you want
    `CALL rank();`

Comment: neat but I'm guessing the first line is not necessary? could I just use in between the tags of "Begin" and "End into a mysql query? (this is out of curiosity)

Comment: first line `CREATE TABLE` is not necessary if you already have a table.

Comment: you have to iterate through the table, so you need stored procedure